# hello, I sent a token ''pyth'' on the solana network. the transaction is processed for more than 2 hours. what should I do?

Tags: solana-program

I sent a token ''pyth'' on the solana network. the transaction is processed for more than 2 hours. what should I do?

Comment: Please add the transaction hash, else it's difficult to tell what the issue might be.